# Process data - in service or controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

This is a question about code organizing and best practices.

Im retreiving data from an api with $resource and I need to process it before sending it to the view.

My question is in what step to process the actual data. My understanding is that it should be done in the service, but I also want to do the actual ajax-call inside the controller.

As it is right now, I inject the service and use functions like CdnService.sumOfVolumeRequest(response) to process the data.

Am I doing it right or is there a better way?

**Service**:

```
function updateVolumeRequest() {
    var params = {
      metric: "size",
      tStart: convertUtcToEpoch(SearchCriteria.criteria.dateFrom),
      tEnd: convertUtcToEpoch(SearchCriteria.criteria.dateTo)
    };
    return params;
  }

  function volumeRequest() {
    return CdnAnalyticsFactory.statsByDimension({
          accountId: Token.UserInfo().Id
        },
        updateVolumeRequest())
      .$promise;
  }
```

**Controller:**

```
  function getData() {
    var data;

    CdnService.sizeRequest(SearchCriteria.criteria.dateFrom, SearchCriteria.criteria.dateTo)
      .then(function onSucess(response) {
        data = CdnService.sumOfVolumeRequest(response)

      });
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to [John Papa's Angular Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#data-services)

> Refactor logic for making data operations and interacting with data to a factory. Make data services responsible for XHR calls, local storage, stashing in memory, or any other data operations.

The question is really this: **Should the service be modular? Should you be able to inject the same service in another controller and retain the same functionality and make it plug and play?**

If you want the service to be self sufficient, then it's better to have the data wrangling in the service itself. The idea is to have the service provide you data in the required format, every time it is called. If you move some of the functionality out, then that code will need to be repeated. This is against the DRY principle.

Of course, it is up to you to *what amount of data manipulation* needs to happen within the service and what amount needs to happen outside.

If the code you're writing in the controller is *logic specific to your controller* then it's fine to write it within the controller. But it's advisable to not include code that'll need to be repeated every time the service is invoked.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context.

If the logic is view independent you can move the code to [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#service) so that you can reuse it in other controllers however if there is a view specific logic you can write in [controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#controller)